# Credit Card travel insurance length

Tags: insurance, payment-cards

Many credit cards offer free travel insurance when you purchase tickets using your credit card, and this will last for 40 days starting from the commencement of your trip.

But what if I purchase further flights and extend my holiday?  e.g. I purchase a flight on the 39th day. Does this extend my travel insurance coverage or start a new insurance policy?

What if I purchase flights on day 41? Does this start a new Insurance policy as if it were a new trip?

Comment: What credit card? Policies are not all the same. Your best bet is to contact the one who issues the policy which is an insurance company on behalf of the credit card usually.

Comment: This question cannot be answered since it depends on your contract. I would also suggest that you call your CC company.

Comment: I think the question is valid, but should be rephrased as : how strict are CC companies about enforcing the length of travel clause? (given CC contract Y allows X days)

Comment: Insurance companies are always strict on that sort of thing!

Comment: You didn't ask re this, but: Some (maybe all?) free insurance offers are for non business use only. If you have ANY business component it  may invalidate your claim. Gold VISA in NZ offer free travel insurance but it is for non business only. Also, the companies need/want to keep their overheads down on this sort of deal so you may get NO acknowledgment of being ensured, no advice if you were disqualified for some reason etc. You only find out when you claim whether you really are covered or not SO you need to do youur homework very carefully indeed. ...

Comment: ... I got bitten by a dog in China and had to have a 4 part Rabies course. I was travelling to and then partially across Australia so has Rabies shots in China , 2 in Australia and one at home in NZ. Only when I got back to NZ did I discover that my "free" VISA travel insurance was not valid :-). 
Only $ in that case - could have made a life and death difference.

Comment: What about your bank? Some bank accounts will give [free travel insurance](http://placetovisit.co.uk/article/free-travel-insurance-for-your-next-trip/) too and may be the travel insurance from your bank can kick in after the credit card one expires on day 40.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  The intent of my question was to see how I this free credit card travel insurance worked and how I might be use it for my travels.  @Kris has given a very good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically -- although this may vary by CC type/issuer -- new coverage can not begin until after you have ended the first trip by returning home.

So if you book a trip and then extend that trip past the 40 days limit without returning home the CC travel insurance will expire at 40 days. The fact that you purchased additional flights does not enter into it.

However, if you book one trip for, say, 30 days, return home and then book another trip about 10 days after getting back, that second trip will be covered as a separate trip with its own 40 day period of coverage.

Unless there is specific language in the insurance terms that come with you CC (which you should read carefully from start to finish) this is the most likely situation. You could also contact the issuer of your CC for details on the policy.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Reading the (long) fine print in the Policy Wording did suggest this